# Numerical methods for modelling non-linear pressure wave propagation in fluids/solids

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, computational-physics

So far, I only have experience solving the Laplace/(inhomogeneous) Helmholtz/Maxwell equation with boundary conditions using the boundary element method (BEM). So far I have used open source tools for this, as my experience is that commercial software is non-transparent and/or expensive.

**Q:** What numerical methods would one use to model non-linear wave propagation in fluids and especially in solids? Are there open source tools out there? Are there similar methods to BEM?

Comment: I am not an expert in numerical modelling but I believe you could very well use Finite-Difference Time-Domain (FDTD) formulations to solve non-linear (as well as linear) wave propagation in fluids. I am not sure about solids but I believe the said method could be used for solids too, as it essentially just replaces derivatives with finite-differences. As I said, I am not an expert and I have only used FDTD for simple linear acoustics in the past.

Comment: You can indeed use FDTD, but it is rather involved.  I am not aware of any open source tools, and I would need to know what you are trying to do before I recommended any commercial software.

Comment: In the meantime, I found that the dual-reciprocity BEM can be used for modelling nonlinear (-shock) wave propagation. If anyone is interested, "The Dual Reciprocity Boundary Element Method" by P. W. Partridge, C. A. Brebbia, L. C. Wrobel, 1991 touches on the topic.